# Dimensionality Reduction Algorithm for Large Dataset?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, large-data

I have a reasonably large (5k variables x 120k cases) that I'd like to run a dimensionality reduction algorithm on. I tried doing a simple Factor Analysis on it in SPSS, but it (predictably) barfed on a 3GB machine. I got an answer by truncating the data set to 2.5k variables and 25k cases, but I started wondering if there is an algorithm other than Factor Analysis/PCA that would handle the data set better.

My background in software development is much stronger than my background in statistics. It's my hope that there's an algorithm that could handle the original, unsampled data set more easily in 3GB of RAM. Does anyone know of such an algorithm?

Forgive me if this is a FAQ; I tried finding the answer before I posted.

**EDIT**: Ideally I'd like an existing implementation in something like R or SPSS, but since I'm a dev, even a software-based solution (like "try this feature of [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)") would be extremely helpful.

Comment: If you are reducing dimensionality, i.e. variables, the data in SPSS should be 120K rows x 5K columns: the 5K x 5K corr. matrix will be analyzed in PCA/Factor. 5K x 5K x 8 = you need roughly only 200Mb RAM (pure minimum; with all front-end expences, 1Gb will suffice surely). Number of rows matter much less in SPSS Factor because the analysis reads row by row. So, there should be no problem except that it will take _time_ to compute and process the corr. matrix. _And_ it will be quicker if you know the number of factors in advance and the number is quite small.

Comment: +1 just for the barfed line.  lol.  Have you looked into sparse matrix formats in R?

Comment: not sure what spss does, but you may be running into memory problems because of the default output produced.  Try to get all output as data sets, and supress any printed/html output.  And only output the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: Are you interested in dimension reduction for the sake of visualizing the data i.e. learning about latent structure in the data? Or are you ultimately interested in using this data for predicting some outcome? What your goal is would determine what algorithms would be worth pursuing.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! 

@ ttnphns Having done a bit of research, it appears that the issue is simply storing the whole data set in memory. 120K*5K*8bytes = 4.8G of memory.

@ probabilityislogic Those are great advice. I think my best bet is going to be to use another algorithm or to try a clever encoding of the data set in memory, per your first suggestion.

@ Sameer Great points. We're interested in understanding the relationships among the variables, which is why Factor Analysis in particular is so interesting.

Comment: @sigpwned. Factor command in SPSS, as far as I know, doesn't store the whole dataset in RAM memory. SPSS, whenever possible, uses memory dynamically and will compute the corr. matrix by reading case by case. It has to store only 5K x 5K matrix in RAM, plus memory to store results. Pity, I can't test your sized data because I have more RAM than that your machine. But I believe my comment was not erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

Random forests are robust.  They are not impacted by outliers.
Gradient boosted trees are great at fitting or over fitting the data.
The combination is fast, handles classical or categorical data, and can handle very large data.

Random forests of gradient boosted trees easily handle problems of this complexity and size.  http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1755828

Comment: Very interesting. I haven't played with random forests. I'll look into them. Thank you!

Comment: I have seen them effectively and conveniently handle data that is 50k rows and 50k cols of mixed type (categorical, integer, continuous).  For going from 50k dimensions to 30 they are great.  Better tools are then used to go from 30 to below.

Comment: Just interested: How are random forests used for dimensionality reduction?

Comment: @Michael - lets say you have 50k variables, and only 30 are relevant.  How do you find the important variables, or maybe the 200 variables with the important ones as an unknown but more accessible subset.  Random forest.  In this way you hae reduced from a 50k dimensional set to a 200 dimensional set.

Comment: @EngrStudent: How would you choose the response variable of the forest?

Comment: @MichaelMayer - what I hear you saying is "give me a sample problem where this is demonstrated.  Is that correct?

Comment: @EngrStudent: Not exactly. I was just wondering how you would apply a random forest (a method for supervised learning) to an unsupervised learning problem. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: With NN or SVM you still specify what variable is the input or the output.  Unsupervised means is a measure of the magnitude of the interventions required during the process.  Like "instant" is a descriptor is cooking, but still requires cooking, it could be argued that there are no truly "unsupervised" learnings, just different degrees of supervision and quality of results.

You can specify inputs and output, let the forest work, then rank the inputs by how much they contribute to the outputs - by how informative they are.  This allows you to cull input streams that are non-informative.

Comment: @EngrStudent: The OP looks for alternatives of PCA and FA, which are both unsupervised learning methods, i.e. they do not use an output variable. I thus wonder how you would apply a random forest without output.

Comment: @MichaelMayer - the original guy did not specify the level of supervision or the requirement for inputs/outputs.  The primary focus was "reduce the dimension" without loss of information.  I will attempt to make a "canonical" example showing some good use case for reduction of dimension of data.